# PHP PDO return headers if there are no results

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Is it possible to return the headers of a PDO query if there are no results as an array in PHP. For example:

```
SELECT 
    fruit.`type` AS 'Type', 
    fruit.`shape` AS 'Shape', 
    fruit.`age` AS 'Age', 
    fruit.`name` AS 'Name' 
    FROM fruit 
    WHERE name = :name;
```

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([
    'name' => 'chicken'
]);
return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Since the above will return no rows is it possible to instead return the SELECT AS so it will return:
`['Type', 'Shape', 'Age', 'Name']`

Comment: No, because "header" is no result.

Comment: you could prolly use `->getColumnMeta()` method right after execution and get the column names, too much work though, you already know the columns and predefined, so just use that array.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, the main reason I don't want to have pre-defined columns is that I'm being given the queries and some of them are quite large so it would be a lot of additional work. The results are being exported to a CSV so I've been asked to only return headers if there are no results.

Comment: 2 separate queries. One to fetch headers and one to fetch rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution to this:

```
if ($stmt->rowCount() < 1) {
    $headers = [];
    foreach(range(0, $stmt->columnCount() - 1) as $index => $column_index)
    {
        $meta[] = $stmt->getColumnMeta($column_index);
        array_push($headers,$meta[$index]['name']);
    }
    return array_values($headers);
}
```